# Pentaho 7.1 and Saiku 3.11 error export to xls

Tags: pentaho, saiku

I'm trying to export a query from saiku to xlsx. I'm having the following error at catalina.out:

2017-07-20 17:37:00,034 ERROR [org.saiku.web.rest.resources.Query2Resource] Cannot get excel for query (410D8A59-5C67-0D09-B32F-46998228997D)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Merged region A1 must contain 2 or more cells

And this message on the screen:

A página da web em http://159.203.87.129:8080/pentaho/plugin/saiku/api/api/query/E2176C55-9B86-8F7B-99DB-3C8E26674EFF/export/xls/flattened pode estar temporariamente indisponível ou pode ter sido movida permanentemente para um novo endereço da web.

This has started since I made an upgrade to pentaho version 7.1 and version 3.11.1 in saiku, both at the community version.

Answer (score 0):

Saiku makes use of the libraries **poi** and **poi-ooxml** for Excel exporting. These libraries are not in saiku/lib/ but in **tomcat/webapps/pentaho/WEB-INF/lib/** (so they depend on the Pentaho version).

In fact, **Pentaho 6** has **poi-3.12.jar** and **poi-ooxml-3.12.jar**, and **Pentaho 7** has **poi-3.15.jar** and **poi-ooxml-3.15.jar**. The latter version of poi implements a security check when merging cells for Excel exporting. Therefore, when you select exactly 1 measure, 1 dimension on columns and 1 dimension on rows (which gives you 2 gray cells at the top corner of the rendering table), you will have this error systematically.

One way to work around is to remove the poi libraries 3.15 and **replace with poi libraries 3.12** from Pentaho 6. Of course, this is not the best way (which involves rewriting Java code inside Saiku).

Answer (score 0):

I think they have solved it in the 8.1 version, but in the 7.1 you can't export a crosstable with more than one column due to a library bug.